# How to capture the last non-missing row in a VBA variable for referencing repeatedly later?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to nativate a spreadsheet that has three columns for each month (Jan-Dec). If the month isn't in the past then the third column should sum the other two (otherwise empty). This should be applied from row 6 to `LastRow`.

My problem is that I can't work out how to correctly use `LastRow`. It needs to be defined beforehand using a different column that I can reply on not having any missing values.

I have been trying to capture this row in `LastRow` but I think I must be doing something fundamentally wrong as I get a type mismatch error for `set sh.LastRow`:

```
Sub Prep_datadump()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Dataset as Range
    Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim Month As Integer

    Set sh.Dataset.Range("C6:C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set LastRow = Dataset.End(xlDown).Row

    For Month = 14 To 47 Step 3
      If Cells(1, Month) >= Date Then
        Sh.Range(Cells(6, Month), Cells(LastRow, Month)).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
      End If
    Next Month
End Sub
```

Comment: Does last row vary based on the column? Consider changing your last row variable to a data type `Long` variable. Then, you won't need to use `Set` to assign the value to it

Comment: Yes it is a monthly data dump where the number of rows can vary month-to-month. Column C is the column I can rely on for identifying the number of rows I need to consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you are having a problem with (`Set LastRow = Dataset.End(xlDown).Row`) attempts to assign the row number of the bottom cell in your `Dataset` range as an integer to your `LastRow` variable. As you first define `LastRow` as a `Range` the code is unable to do this action as it is a different variable type and so you receive the mismatch error.

Try changing your `Dim LastRow As Range` line to `Dim LastRow As Integer`

Comment: Thank you - although I've tried that and it returns a compile error saying "Object required" for `Set LastRow = CBS.End(xlDown).Row`?

Comment: Apologies, you need to also remove the `Set` on that line.

Comment: Great thank you very much! It works now - so `set` is only to be used for instantiating objects I take it?

Comment: Do you think last row that way works? What happens if row 6 is the last one and you do xlDown.end? OT: integer is "deprecated", you may google integer vs long; in short, instead of integer use Long.